# PHP Extract each occurrence of an item within a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

In the event of a string that says:

> Once upon a time a small young LKTgoblingLKT had an unfortunate accident and LKTfellLKT.

How could I extract each occurrence of content contained within `LKT` into an array and replace them in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

- Store the sentence in a variable
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) the sentence with space as the delimiter
- Loop through the array
- Check if the word contains your string using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos)
- If it does, push the word into the result array

Something like this:

```
$string = '...';
$words = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($word, 'LKT') !== FALSE) {
        $result[] = $word;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => LKTgoblingLKT
    [1] => LKTfellLKT.
)
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/K8hEtF5h)

---

If you want the string to be replaced with another word, you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), like so:

```
$string = '...';
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$result = array();

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($word, 'LKT') !== FALSE) {
        $word = str_replace($word, 'FOO', $word);
    }
        $result[] = $word;
}

$resultString = implode(' ', $result);
echo $resultString;
```

Output:

```
Once upon a time a small young FOO had an unfortunate accident and FOO
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/C3KoIUro)

Comment: `array_walk($result, function(&$v){ $v = trim($v, 'LKT'); });` might be useful here (: